# Is the position of the clause in this sentence okay?

Tags: sentence-patterns

I’m trying to figure out if this sentence is ordered properly. Is it okay to start the sentence with this clause — "From the moment someone requests ..." — which really modifies the "customer experience"? Please don't tell me to just tack it onto the end of the sentence. The company doesn't want to start with "Here's how ..."

> From the moment a customer requests help to the minute that help is given, here’s how to improve every step of the customer experience.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this grammatically, but if you really want to improve every step in the customer experience, you'll need to check back with the customer on the help that was provided and act constructively on the customer's feedback.

Comment: The sentence seems fine.  Others might write it differently, but this is just personal choice.

Comment: Starting the second part with *Here's how* seems incongruous or out of place. Something like *,there's a way to* would flow a bit better. The beginning is correct but the rest seems as I say, odd.

Comment: Well, if the company doesn't want to make it clear to its employees that these are instructions, they can obviously say anything they want. But burying the important part (_here's how,_ which identifies the answer to a presumed question about method) in the middle behind an irrelevant path metaphor is not very good management.

Comment: Since you don't use a colon at the end of the sentence, you could drop the unusual **here's how** altogether in a couple of ways (the context isn't entirely clear). (1) *From the moment a customer requests help to the minute that help is given, **we improve** every step of the customer experience.* (2) *From the moment a customer requests help to the minute that help is given, **strive to improve** every step of the customer experience.*

Comment: I'm assuming that this introductory sentence will be followed by a new paragraph and actual steps to accomplish the improvement.